# Why do I get a stack overflow error on this code?

Tags: java, arrays, stack, overflow

Basically, I'm trying to generate an  array of 9 integers which contains the numbers 1-9 in a way that they are not duplicated.

```
public static int[] generate (){

    //new int array
    int[] arr = new int[9];

    //filling the array with random numbers
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        arr[i]=rand.nextInt(9)+1;
    }

    //boolean which turns true if a number is twice in the array
    boolean same=false;

    //checking if there are double numbers
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<arr.length;j++){
            if(arr[i]==arr[j]){
                same=true;
            }
        }
    }

    //returning the array if all numbers are different
    if(same==false){
        return arr;
    }

    //repeating if there is a double number
    else{
        return generate();
    }
}
```

I know that the code might be very inefficient but I am quite new to Java and I want to solve it in a way like that. I'm very thankful for every help!

Comment: Your return statement calls the method again causing infinite recursion (infinite until you run out stack memory). Don't do that; don't call the method `generate()` within itself. Instead return an int array. If the array is not correct, fix it before you return it, but don't use recursion to do this.

Comment: If you must use recursion, then you must make sure that the recursed method call uses different data, meaning it would require passing in parameters, else there would be a guarantee that the recursion would never stop, but you don't need to use recursion here, nor should you. Myself, I'd create an `ArrayList<Integer>` and then would call `Collections.shuffle(...)` on it.

Comment: do this instead:

`public static int[] generate (){
`

   int[] arr = new int[]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};


    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
     int randomTarget = rand.nextInt(9);
     int temp = arr[i];
     arr[i] = arr[randomTarget];
     arr[randomTarget] = temp;
    }
    
 return arr;
}

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: Why is the recursion infinite? When the array contains of differing numbers, the boolean same stays false and the int[] arr is being returned? Or: where is the difference to this code (which works):

static int one(){
     int i = rand.nextInt(9)+1;
     if (i != 1){
          return one();
     }
     else{
          return i;
     }
}
It also is recursive, calls itself and returns always the int 1?

Comment: @Marco recursion in your code is most likely to happen. It is not infinite, but chances are will cause a stackoverflow before it finishes.

Comment: @Ammar: Thanks a lot, that was new to me. I thought the garbage collector would clean the stack from the unused arrays...

Comment: The GC doesn't clean the stack, only the heap. The arrays *are* on the heap (they're just *referenced* from the stack), and likely do get cleaned, but that won't prevent stack overflow.